# What is the difference between declaring List<Integer> vs ArrayList<Integer>?

Tags: java, collections

```
List<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<Integer> mylist2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I am wondering what is the actual difference between the above two in java collections API. I am new to java collections API. I know that List is an interface that ArrayList class implements.

Comment: the difference is the 2nd form is better:)

Comment: @irreputable: I think you mistyped.

Comment: @Keppil no. when declaring a variable, a more concrete type is better; in this case, ArrayList.

Comment: @irreputable: That's just wrong. Although there are cases where declaring the actual type is better, in general the best practice is to declare the interface type.

Comment: @irreputable: I disagree. To be specific - use the most "broad" type you are going to need. If you have a method that only uses `hashCode()` and `toString()` - use `Object` - it will allow you to refactor the code much easier later on. This is especially true when talking about instance and class variables.

Comment: @amit especially false for instance/class variables; their types need to be explicit more than local variables.

Comment: @irreputable What happens if you need to convert the Array list to a linked list? You would not be able to simply cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your statement 1, since you are referring `mylist` as `List<Integer>` while it is still `ArrayList<Integer>`, **hence you can use the methods available in the `List` interface ONLY.** This is better statement, if you are using cross class.method functionality.

Also any method accepting `List<Integer>` can accept any of the implementation classes of `List` e.g. `LinkedList<Integer>` or your custom implementation class.

Your second statement, creates and references the object as `ArrayList<Integer>` ONLY. Some people perefer it when `mylist` is to be used locally in the method.

Comment: Thanx man, your explanation has made it very clear. So, it means for mylist i can use all methods of List interface but for mylist i can only use methods of ArrayList class. right?

Answer (score 8):

The `List<Integer>` version is the interface type - it only allows you to perform the methods declared by the interface, while the `ArrayList<Interger>` typed variable allows you to do anything that is declared in the `ArrayList<Interger>` and its supers. (including the `List` of course).

However, though it seems "useless" to chose the first - **it actually allows you more flexibility** - it will help you change your design much easier if you will later decide you want a `LinkedList<Interger>` (for example) and not an `ArrayList<Interger>` as the dynamic type.

---

**Addition:**

Of course it doesn't mean you need to *automatically* chose the `List<Integer>` version. If you actually need to use the exact type of `ArrayList` - you should chose it. A good rule of thumb is to start with the interface version, and change it to the `ArrayList<Integer>` only if you find yourself straggling to get something you would have done very easily with an `ArrayList` type (or if you find yourself casting to an `ArrayList`...)

Answer (score 2):

**Always** code to the interface.

(Car analogy alert)

You walk into Hertz Rent-a-Car.  You say, I want an `IVehicle`.  They say, "well, what *kind* of `IVehicle`?"  You don't care.  So they give you a `DumpTruck`.  But you don't want a dump truck, you want something compact.  You want an `ICompact` that extends `IVehicle`.  So they give you a motorcycle.  "No!" you exclaim, "I want an `ICar`!"  "What kind of `ICar`?" they ask. "I don't care!" you exclaim.  So they give you a `FordCar`, and you live happily ever after.

Does that clear it up?

Answer (score 1):

First one is called coding to interfaces.

Using the `List` reference through out your code you can update the concrete implementation to something else like a `LinkedList` without breaking your client code.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of it as polymorphism.

`List<Integer> mylist` declares it to be a List, but it doesn't have to be an ArrayList - JVM just knows that it implements the List interface.

`ArrayList<Integer> mylist2` declares it to be an ArrayList, so JVM knows that not only is it a List, it's an ArrayList in particular.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that List is an interface that ArrayList class implements.

That's exactly the difference :)

When you're using the two variables (mylist) and (mylist2) in code, you would have access to any methods that ArrayList defines that aren't part of the basic List interface only on mylist2.

Answer (score 0):

For `myList`, you will only be able to invoke methods of the `List` interface.

For example, you cannot invoke the method `ensureCapacity` on myList.