# Difference between ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); and Collection<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Tags: java

I don't understand difference between:

1. `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
2. `Collection<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Class `ArrayList` extends class which implements interface `Collection`, so Class `ArrayList` implements `Collection` interface. Maybe `list1` allows us to use static methods from the `Collection` interface?

Comment: Closely related: [What is the difference between declaring List<Integer> vs ArrayList<Integer>?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13709795/572670)

Comment: With `Collection<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();`, you can't call `list1.get(0);` for example (won't compile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we're dealing with here is the difference between **interface** and **implementation**.

An interface is a set of methods without any regard to how those methods are implemented. When we instantiate an object as having a type that is actually an `interface`, what we're saying is that it is an object that implements all of the methods in that `interface`... but doesn't provide is with access to any of the methods in the `class` that actually provides those implementations.

When you instantiate an object with the type of an implementing `class`, then you have access to all of relevant methods of that `class`. Since that `class` is implementing an `interface`, you have access to the methods specified in the interface, plus any extras provided by the implementing class.

Why would you want to do this? Well, by restricting the type of your object to the `interface`, you can switch in new implementations without worrying about changing the rest of your code. This makes it a whole lot more flexible.

Answer (score 12):

An interface has no static methods [in Java 7]. `list1` allows to access only the methods in `Collection`, whereas `list` allows to access all the methods in `ArrayList`.

---

It is preferable to declare a variable with its least specific possible type. So, for example, if you change `ArrayList` into `LinkedList` or `HashSet` for any reason, you don't have to refactor large portions of the code (for example, client classes).

Imagine you have something like this (just for illustrational purposes, not compilable):

```
class CustomerProvider {
    public LinkedList<Customer> getAllCustomersInCity(City city) {
        // retrieve and return all customers for that city
    }
}
```

and you later decide to implement it returning a `HashSet`. Maybe there is some client class that relies on the fact that you return a `LinkedList`, and calls methods that `HashSet` doesn't have (e.g. `LinkedList.getFirst()`).

That's why you better do like this:

```
class CustomerProvider {
    public Collection<Customer> getAllCustomersInCity(City city) {
        // retrieve and return all customers for that city
    }
}
```

Comment: So list1 is an ArrayList, but can use only methods from Collection interfase? And method Collections.sort(list1) is acces only for list1, but not for list?

Answer (score 2):

The difference, as others have said, is that you are limited to the methods defined by the `Collection` interface when you specify that as your variable type. But that doesn't answer the question of why you would want to do this.

The reason is that the choice of data type provides information to the people using the code. Especially when used as the parameter or return type from a function (where outside programmers may have no access to the internals).

In order of specificity, here is what different type choices might tell you:

- `Collection` - a group of objects, with no further guarantees. The consumer of this object can iterate over the collection (with no guarantees as to iteration order), and can learn its size, but cannot do anything else.
- `List` - a group of objects that have a specific order. When you iterate over these objects, you will always get them in the same order. You can also retrieve specific items from the collection by index, but you cannot make any assumptions about the performance of such retrieval.
- `ArrayList` - a group of objects that have a specific order, and may be accessed by index in constant time.

And although you didn't ask about them, here are some other collection classes:

- `Set` a group of objects that is guaranteed to contain no duplicates per the `equals()` method. There are no guarantees regarding the iteration order of these objects.
- `SortedSet` a group of objects that contains no duplicates, and will always iterate in a specific order (although that specific order is not guaranteed by the collection).
- `TreeSet` a group of ordered objects with no duplicates, that exhibits `O(logN)` insert and retrieval times.
- `HashSet` a group of objects with no duplicates, that does not have an inherent order, but provides (amortized) constant-time access.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that you're providing access to list1 through the Collection interface, whereas you provide access to list2 through the ArrayList interface. Sometimes, providing access through a restricted interface is useful, in that it promotes encapsulation and reduces dependence on implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform operations on "list1", you'll only be able to access methods from the Collection interface (get, size, etc.). By declaring "list" as an ArrayList, you gain access to additional methods only defined in the ArrayList class (ensureCapacity and trimToSize, for example.

It's typically best practice to declare the variable as the least specific class you need. So, if you only need the methods from Collection, use it. Typically in this case, that would mean using List, which lets you know it's ordered and can handle duplicates.

Using the least specific class/interface allows you to freely change the implementation later. For example, if you later learn that a LinkedList would be a better implementation to use, you could change it without breaking all your code if you define the variable to be a List.